# How can I import Proguard obfuscated module into Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

I have written a java library that I don't want users to be able to see the source code. Hence I used proguard to obfuscated by java library into debug and release AAR. I'm trying to test the obfuscation in a demo project by importing it as an AAR file. When I import the release AAR file, everything is obfuscated and I'm not even able to resolve the symbols.

Is there any way I can obfuscate the source code but allow the AAR to be imported into another project? Similar to a static library/framework in iOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure to keep the class names and methods 'as is' for those classes that are accessed externally by apps using your library.

For example, to keep all public methods and variables declared by a class used by outside apps, add the following to your `proguard-project.txt` file:

```
-keep public class com.your.class {public *;}
```

See [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I got the obfuscation to work! one last thing is I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/hash/Hashing;` for some of external library that I used. I tried ````-keep public class com.google.common.** {
    public *;
}```` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try adding this
 `-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Deprecated,EnclosingMethod`